# Rails accessing a model's nested Hash value in a where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a `Review` model, which contains a field, `answer`. `answer` is a simple hash. Edit: `answer` is stored as a `jsonb` in the database.

```rb
create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.jsonb "answer", default: {}
end
```

The `Review` model's fields are as follows:

```rb
  id: 1,
  venue_id: 1,
  answer:
   {
     "loved_subject": "atmosphere",
     "hated_subject": "service"
   },
    ...
```

I want to grab all Reviews where the `answer[:loved_subject]` is equal to `"atmosphere"`

So far I've tried variations on the below:

```rb
Review.where(answer: { loved_subject: "atmosphere" })
```

It doesn't error out, but it only returns an empty array. I know 100% for a fact that there do exist entries where `loved_subject` is indeed `"atmosphere"`, so obviously my query is being written out incorrectly.

How would I go about writing out this query?

Comment: How is answer stored in the database?

Comment: @BenStephens answers are stored as a `jsonb` in the DB. `create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t| t.jsonb "answer", default: {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `answer` is a `jsonb` as specified in the edit, you can use [jsonb queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html):

```rb
Review.where("answer->>'loved_subject' = ?", 'atmosphere')
```

Comment: Had to use a double right arrow `->>`, but other than that it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: You'd use `->>` instead of `->` because `->` returns a `jsonb` value whereas `->>` returns a `text` value.